# RegEx for only 1 URL

Tags: regex

please help with regex for only 1 url. Meaning, user is not suppose to be able to supply two urls seperated by comma or other seperator. is that possible? what's the best solution?
thanks

Comment: i also found this: http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty here: http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&c=-1&m=5&ps=20

Ensure you add ^ at the beginning to denote the start of the string, and $ to denote the end.

If you only need a single URL, then any other URLs the user adds would make the entire string an invalid URL, so you win.